# Restlet On Android - Issues with serialization

Tags: java, android, serialization, restlet, deserialization

I am trying to retrieve serialized classes using Restlet 2.1 with Android as the client and GAE as the server. This is the relevant code:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://localhost:8888/mydata");
// Get the MyData object
MyDataResource resource = cr.wrap(MyDataResource.class);
MyData myData = resource.retrieve();
```

I initially tested this in a standalone JSE class, and everything worked fine.
When I try to run the same thing in Android, the myData object is null. Any ideas?

Comment: post the logcat output please

Comment: From my tests, the logcat had a warning: `Unable to find a converter for this representation : [application/json,UTF-8]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check here the Android specificities:
[RESTLet android page](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/275-restlet/266-restlet.html)

I spent few hours before to understand the problem as well, you need to explicitly register the Jackson convertor like that :

```
Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredConverters().add(new JacksonConverter());
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. Your answer put me on the road to recovery from the path to insanity trying to figure this one out. I had other issues to figure out, but this was the catalyst. I even read the page you linked to before, but completely forgot about it.

Comment: Life saver, though I don't see anything related in the provided link: http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/275-restlet/266-restlet.html :(

Comment: There is a wrong url in this answer. The correct one (to restlet android info page) is as follows: http://restlet.org/learn/guide/2.2/editions/android/

Corrected the original post as well.

Comment: I imported org.restlet.android:2.2.2 and it doesn't have the ext package so I don't have the JacksonConverter class, can someone explains me why ?

Comment: All these links are dead now :(