# Restlet : Unable to find a converter for this representation : [application/json,UTF-8]

Tags: java, restlet-2.0

I have researched this quite heavily but have been unable to find a solution. I have created the simplest unit test to fetch a single entity but am still receiving the "Unable to find converter" exception. I have included the org.restlet.ext.servlet.jar,org.json.jar and org.restlet.ext.net.jar in my class path. I am also able to see the json returned and have been able to print using the cr.get(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) method.

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://localhost:8888/r/establishment/29");
Establishment est = cr.get(Establishment.class);
System.out.println("Establishment name is " + est.getName());
```

I am using restlet-gae-2.1rc6 on GAE vs 1.7.1

Comment: You might want to edit your question and put in relevant information - describe your problem, show us what research you've done. The way it stands now, I don't think anyone can understand your issue.

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to submit the question. I was in the middle and was checking out some things using debugger. I did notice that the Converter service getBestHelper was called multiple times and it was finding the org json converter but on later iterations it was not finding the correct converter and falling through to the else in the toRepresentation method. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, causing any value retrieved from the server to be null. @ChrisHinshaw, Did you solve it?

Comment: I switched to jersey for my rest api and have been very happy with it. Sorry probably not the answer you were looking for but Jersey worked much better for my needs. One thing though make sure you are specifying the accept type when building your client resource. You should set the accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) if using json. This was probably the issue with my implementation.

Comment: RE Jersey, I couldn't make Jersey work on google app engine - dependency issues.

Comment: RE your issue, I found the solution. You just needed to register a converter. See a more descriptive explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19593796/435605

Answer (score 2):

You need to register a converter. Example:

```
Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredConverters().add(new JacksonConverter());
```

See a question with the same solution but a different problem: [Android to gae restlet example doesn't work on the Android side](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19593337/435605)

I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5205993/435605