# Android to gae restlet example doesn't work on the Android side

Tags: android, json, google-app-engine, restlet

I'm trying to run [restlet's first application example](http://restlet.org/learn/guide/2.1/introduction/first-steps/first-application) - android to gae - but the value returned is alway null, showing a warning in Android's LogCat: `Unable to find a converter for this representation : [application/json,UTF-8]`

The specific code that returns null is this line:

```
Contact contact = resource.retrieve();
```

My Assumption that it's a conversion issue. If so, i'm surprised it's just a warning.

Any idea how to go from here?

Some notes:

- I use restlet 2.1.4
- I used curl to test the server side and it works great. Example: `curl -i -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8888/contacts/123`
- To test Android against a local server, I use the following ip: 10.0.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Yes, found a solution.

I just needed to register a converter - Specifically Jackson converter. Found the solution in the following SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5205993/435605

```
Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredConverters().add(new JacksonConverter());
```

The registration I did in Android's application class as it's a global registration.